# Area of the common region of three circles.

Tags: calculus, area, polar-coordinates

> Find the area of the region that is common to the circles $r = 1$, $r = 2 \cos θ$, and $r = 2 \sin θ$.

I tried many ways to get the common region, but it seems impossible to eliminate to that point, but I am not sure about that either.*I just need a cue.*

It is a problem from Howard Anton Calculus 9th edition  (page 764, Q.25). I couldn't get the Solution Manual free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is supposed to be a comment but I need to post the picture.

---

Hint: The area you want is the triangular region  $ABC$ bounded by 3 circular arcs.
You can decompose it into two [circular segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) ($AC$, $AB$ in red) and one [circular sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector) ($ABC$ in orange).

[image: Intersection of 3 circles]